# How to add a element between two elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

My DOM currently looks like this:

```
<body>
  <h1> </h1>
  <button> </button>
  <p> </p>
```

Upon click of the button, I want to add another `p` in between button and the initial `p`. I have tried prepending to the initial `p`, but it's not looking like what I want it to. I have also tried appending to button, but it's adopting the style of button, which I also don't want.

Ideally, I would like to retain the styling of the initial `p`, but add another individual block of p right before the initial one. How can I achieve this, preferably with append/prepend?

Comment: you can use `after()`

Comment: Using jQuery? Plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JQuery there is a method for that, it´s called before.
http://api.jquery.com/before/, will work fine in combination with the :first-child selector.

```
var count=0;
$('button').on('click', function () {
  count++;
    $("#paragraphs p:first-child").before($('<p>New Paragraph #' + count + '</p>'));
});
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcebqxt5/)

Comment: looks like it's deleting my initial p element!

Comment: Uhhhh you down voted me? I'm so sad now. Haha, the jsfiddle has your code working.

Comment: I didn't click down vote... I don't know why it did that

Answer (score 1):

This is a very rough draft of what you may want to try doing. Instead of attacking the issue from the paragraph attack it from the button if the DOM state is going to stay the same.

The code should look something like this

```
function addParagraph(sender) {
    $(sender).after( "<p>Test</p>" );
}
```

And you can you the onclick event of the button like this (This can be changed to anything else you might want to use)

```
<button onclick="addPara(this)">Add Paragraph</button>
```

Now because your structure is always

```
<h1></h1>
<button></button>
<p></p>
```

It will always push the new element right after the button and always before the next element in the structure. The alternative is to do what Gus has done and create a DIV container and keep pushing new elements into the first place in the DIV.